# c# webbrowser browsing website with custom IE version but no effect for some people

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, version

Sorry if the subject isn't that clear, what I meant is, I have made a c# application which browsers local hosted html page, I made it like that to make the application design looks a bit better than what we can do with c#....

it working perfectly for me and for some other people and showing like that:

[image]

and on other hand it was just not changing version for some other people and showing not supporting javascript error(s):

[image]

Any one know the reason?
I would be so glad if anyone would help me on solving this problem.

I have the code

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=11" />
```

in the html page but it doesn't effect on some users webbrowser version....

Comment: Just to clarify, this website is hosted on each person's PC (i.e. hosted locally)?  If so, then perhaps those that receiving the javascript error do not have the "C:\Program Files\SA-MP\....\jquery.min.js" path on their PC.

Comment: Actually it exist, I've checked it through teamviwer, the only problem is webrowser IE version was 8 above / below...
so it wasn't supporting javascripts....

Comment: Are you sure you want it to execute in ie11 mode, how about the ones using ie8 or ie9. You may want to revisit you decision of which versiin to support. But to actually sort your problem you need to debug javascript and find the area which is causing the issue. Once problem is identified you may either choose to change ie version you want to support or fix the code causing problem

Comment: Also you may need browser definition files in root folder

Comment: There's nothing wrong with javascript codes, and yes I wanna use IE 11, the problem is IE 8 doesn't even support javascript.

may you explain more about browser definition files?